# Using Capistrano to deploy a Rails application to multiple web servers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano

I'm currently setting up a new production environment for a Rails application which includes multiple, load-balanced application servers (currently only two, but this will increase over time).

I'd like to handle deployment of the app to all these servers in a single command using Capistrano (which I already use for my existing, single server).  The only way I can see of doing this is to use `capistrano-ext` (which I actually already use to deploy to my test and staging environments), by defining a new 'environment' for each application server (`app1`, `app2` and so on) and performing a deployment using something like:

```
cap app1 app2 app3 deploy
```

Is this the recommended way of doing it or is there a better approach?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yeah. Capistrano manages multiple servers natively. No need for capistrano ext.
You only need to define multiple [roles](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/wiki/Roles)

```
role :app, "myserver.example.com"
role :db,  "mysecondserver.example.com"
```

By default your tasks will be executed on every server. But you can limit a task to one or some servers only.

```
task :migrate, :roles => [:app, :db] do
    # ...
end
```

Here, the task will be executed only on the app and db roles.

You can do the same with the run method.

```
run "rake db:migrate", :roles => :db
```

The rake db:migrate will be run only on the db server.

Comment: Note on above config.  Multiple app servers would look like:
role :app, "app1.example.com", "app2.example.com", "app3.example.com"

Answer (score 36):

Assuming [capistrano multistage](http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2007/7/23/capistrano-multistage):

In `config/deploy/production`:

```
role :app, "server1", "server2", "server3"
```

Now a `cap deploy production` will deploy to all 3 servers.

Comment: what do i do if i want multiple servers using production environment, but still be able to deploy to one specific server? Given your example: just deploy to "server1", but having just production.rb, is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

This is what I have tried in `rails 4`:

**config/deploy.rb:**

```
role :app, %w{server1 server2 server3}
```