# Rails 4 capistrano deploy to multiple servers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

I have my app deployed on multiple servers and each have their own database. How do I deploy the app with "cap deploy production" to all servers?

This is my **production.rb**

```
role :web, "123.456.78.90"
role :app, "123.456.78.90"
role :db,  "123.456.78.90", :primary => true
set :rails_env, "production"
set :user, "root"
set :password, "password"
```

I would need capistrano to also deploy it to the following:

```
role :web, "567.890.12.34"
role :app, "567.890.12.34"
role :db,  "567.890.12.34", :primary => true
set :rails_env, "production"
set :user, "root"
set :password, "password"
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Capistrano to deploy a Rails application to multiple web servers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661868/using-capistrano-to-deploy-a-rails-application-to-multiple-web-servers)

Comment: or this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2633758/deploying-a-rails-app-to-multiple-servers-using-capistrano-best-practices?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your **production.rb**

```
role :app, %w{s01.foo.com s02.foo.com}, user: 'root'
role :web, %w{s01.foo.com s02.foo.com}, user: 'root'
```