# Updating Version in Multiple Websites by using Git

Tags: git, git-merge

I have 12 websites in 2 different servers, using the same code base. I want to update versions with a single `git push`. 12 websites in 2 different servers should be updated with a single push. I am using Git (bitbucket).

How can I do that?

Comment: Capistrano - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661868/using-capistrano-to-deploy-a-rails-application-to-multiple-web-servers

Comment: Just to elaborate, if you've not used it, it's not just for Rails apps.  I use BitBucket and Capistrano for deployment of our Magento and Wordpress sites.  It is awesome, you will never look back.